# Proof verification: Unique smallest topology on family of topologies containing all other topologies.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $(T_\alpha)$ be a family of topologies on X. Show that there is a unique smallest topology on X containing all the topologies $T_\alpha$.

The proof I have goes as follows:

1. Consider the set $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$. Define this set to be the union of all topologies in $(T_\alpha)$.
2. Munkres definition of a subbasis for a topology on $X$ is that it is a collection of subsets of which an arbitrary union is all of $X$. Hence $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$ is trivially a subbasis for a topology on $X$.
3. The topology for which $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$ is a subbasis is the "subbasis-generated topology" (term I came up with myself because I didn't find any name which is more concise). This topology, which I will call $T_U$ is the set of all possible unions of all possible finite intersections of all sets in $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$. Hence the set of all possible finite intersections acts as a basis for $T_U$, call this set $I$.
4. To prove that $T_U$ is the smallest possible topology with the desired property I proceeded as follows: Suppose there was a smaller topology containing the elements of all other topologies, call this topology $T_S$. Then $\exists C\in T_U: C\notin T_S$. Since $C\in T_U$, $C$ is the union of some $X_\alpha \in I$.
5. Since $C\notin T_S$ any basis generating $T_S$ lacks at least one of the previously mentioned $X_\alpha$'s necessary to form $C$. Why? If that was not the case, one could simply form the union of all the $X_\alpha$'s to get $C$, which would imply $C$ is in $T_S$ - contrary to our assumption.
6. Because there is an $X_\alpha$ lacking in any basis of $T_S$ then at least one such $X_\alpha$ is also lacking in $T_S$. Why? Well, $T_S$ is a basis of itself, so if it contained all of the $X_\alpha$'s necessary for the formation of $C$, it could form $C$ by union. However, since $T_S$ does not contain $C$, it would violate our assumption again.
7. Now it follows that $X_\alpha$ lacking in $T_S$ implies that there is a certain $T_\alpha\in (T_\alpha)$ for which there is an $X\in T_\alpha$ such that $X \notin T_S$. Why? Suppose no such $T_\alpha$ existed, then all elements in $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$ would be in $T_S$, meaning all finite intersections would be in $T_S$, implying the existence of $C$ in $T_S$. Hence no such $T_S$ can exist.
8. As for the uniqueness: Suppose there was another topology $T_C$ such that $T_C$ contains all elements of $\bigcup_\alpha T_\alpha$. Assume that $T_C\neq T_U$.
9. Then one of the following three scenarios must be true: i) $T_C\subset T_U \wedge T_U\not\subset T_C$, ii) $T_U\subset T_C \wedge T_C\not\subset T_U$, iii) $T_C\not\subset T_U \wedge T_U\not\subset T_C$.
10. The argument in i) is equivalent to the argument presented in showing $T_U$ is the smallest possible set. ii) would imply that $T_c$ is not really the smallest possible set, and the argument in iii) would also be false by the same argument that makes i) false. Hence $T_C\neq T_U$ leads to a contradiction, so $T_C = T_U$ must be true.

My 2 big questions are as follows:

A) Is the proof correct?

B) Is there an easier proof? I must admit, I'm a bit tired and spent all day trying to solve this so I might have just overlooked a simpler solution.

Comment: This looks like a very long proof. Actually, it is much easier: just take the intersection of all topologies on $X$ which contain the topologies $T_{\alpha}$. It is easy to check that any intersection of topologies is a topology, and clearly it is the smallest one which contains them all. (and note that the set of topologies which contain all of the $T_{\alpha}$ is not empty, because the discrete topology clearly contains them all. So the intersection is well defined)

Comment: @Mark As I just noticed this is exactly what my proof does but I can't really find a shorter proof of that being the smallest set

Comment: The proof of this being the smallest topology is almost trivial with the solution I suggested. If $T$ is a topology which contains all of the $T_{\alpha}$ then it is one of the topologies which we intersect, and so it contains the intersection we defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all topologies on $X$ which contain all of the topologies $(T_{\alpha})$. Note that $\mathcal{F}$ is not empty, because the discrete topology on $X$ clearly belongs there. And now let:

$\mathcal{T}=\bigcap\limits_{T\in\mathcal{F}}T$

It is easy to check that any intersection of topologies on $X$ is again a topology, and so $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$. Every $T\in\mathcal{F}$ contains the topologies $(T_{\alpha})$, and so the intersection $\mathcal{T}$ contains them as well. Moreover, it is the smallest topology on $X$ which contains them. For if $T$ is a topology on $X$ which contains all of the $(T_{\alpha})$ then $T\in\mathcal{F}$, and so $\mathcal{T}\subseteq T$ by definition.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your explanation. I would still greatly appreciate it if you (or anyone, for that matter) took some time to review my answer :)